# can we swap the order of execution (top to bottom changed as bottom to top) based on flag?

Tags: tcl

i have an if loop loop where i configure commands in router as

```
    mode contains config or unconfig as values

if {[regexp -nocase {^config$} $mode]} {

set conf ""

} else {

 set conf no

}

 $router config "$conf primary command\n"

 $router config "$conf secondary command\n"
```

when mode is set to config everthing is fine , primary command is configured first and then secondary command"
but while unconfiguring i want secondary command to executed first 
and then only it allows me to remove primary command...so when $mode changes will i be able to swap the order of execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having your code keep a list of operations to perform as the user lists them instead of executing them immediately, only actually performing the operations on some signal. Then swapping the order of execution is just a matter of processing the list in the reverse direction, which is pretty trivial (and `lreverse` might help).

I'd not personally be inclined to do it though. The usual Tcl way is to do things immediately and in the order specified; the only notable exceptions to this are Tk (which postpones display and layout “until idle”, i.e. when there are no pending events) and Expect in some uses (and that's partial; you can `expect` many things at once, but they're checked for in the order specified).

Comment: thanks did it with lreverse , though i am using package require tclx , it says lreverse unknown command, anyway used a proc for lreverse.,it worked

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
if {$conf == "no"} {
    $router config "$conf primary command\n"
    $router config "$conf secondary command\n"
} else {
    $router config "$conf secondary command\n"
    $router config "$conf primary command\n"
}
```

Comment: thanks i thought of that , but i have more commands and just for example primary command have 5 to 6 variables to be substituted based on loops...it will looking complicated and lengthy

Answer (score 0):

```
proc myConf {cmd} {
  global myConfs router

  $router config "$cmd\n"
  lappend myConfs $cmd
}

# configure
set myConfs {}
myConf "primary command"
myConf "secondary command"

# unconfigure
foreach cmd [lreverse $myConfs] {
  $router config "no $cmd\n"
}
```